# Can you stack the effect of the Crafter's Fortune spell by drinking potions of it?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting, stacking, potions

If you were to craft potions of *crafter's fortune*, could you stack the effect by drinking multiple potions to get a +10 or +15 or your next Craft check?

The description of [*crafter's fortune*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/crafter-s-fortune/) states that the duration is 1 day per level or until discharged; it doesn't specifically state that they can't be stacked. I personally feel that this would be possible because it takes 1 round to drink a potion, so it would be 18 seconds to drink 3 potions and then you craft your item.

For background, I am a mutated monkey into a vanaran with a high Intelligence and a custom feat to increase the number of potions I brew at one time by my Intelligence modifier. I also have plans for economic domination using my potions.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to RPG.SE! When you get a chance, you might want to check out the [tour] and [help], which explain a lot more about how this site works. This is a great first question, and I hope we can help you with it!

Answer (score 8):

### You can't stack *crafter's fortune*.

The spell description for [*crafter's fortune*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/crafter-s-fortune/) states:

> The target ... gains a +5 luck bonus on its next Craft skill check.

Luck is a type of bonus. According to the rules on [bonus types](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Bonus),

> Most bonuses have a type, and as a general rule, bonuses of the same type are not cumulative (do not “stack”)—only the greater bonus granted applies.

Since each casting of the spell (or draught of potion) is applying a luck bonus, the bonuses do not stack with each other. You only get a +5 bonus to your Craft check.